# cross browser - onblur - javascript function

Tags: javascript, onblur

so I have this code:

```
<?php $today = date('Y-m-d'); ?>
<script>
function maggiorenne () {

//get today's date  
today = "<?=$today ?>";
today = dateToTimestamp(today);

console.log(today);

// get birth date
birthdate = $("#datepickernascita").val();
// console.log(birthdate);
birthdate=dateToTimestamp(birthdate);

//check if the user is 18 or less
age=today-birthdate
document.getElementById('minorenne').style.display='none';

if(age < 567648000000){

document.getElementById('minorenne').style.display='block';                   
}
};
</script>
```

plus this:

```
<input type="text" id="datepickernascita" name="datepickernascita" class="validate[required,custom[date]]" onblur="maggiorenne()"/>
```

I've done many internet searches, but i can't understand why it is only working on chrome and not on other browsers. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you defined a `dateToTimestamp()` function?

Comment: yes sure i defined it. you can see a working demo here: ilsestante.webservicestudio.eu/form.php

on the 4th field (data di nascita) add 1999-01-01 and then click out. It is working on chrome, but no on other browsers

Comment: You should change the question to include only the HTML response.

Comment: I think i don't get what you mean styfle

Comment: `dateToTimestamp()` is not returning appropriate data. It seems that you're moving the "year" to the end of the string, which is not a [format recognized by Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse), causing an "Invalid Date" and returning "NaN". You should be able to pass the date you provided (1999-01-01) directly into `Date()` without first manipulating the string.

Comment: awesome, thank you very much showdev. I actually copied this from another stackoverflow answer, and that was the one creating the problem ;)

solved

Comment: I'd love to mark this as solved and give you some sort of point for helping me, I looked around but have no idea on how to do it

Comment: Yeah, I didn't post an answer because my information didn't constitute a complete answer. If you like, post the solution you came up with and accept your own answer :D